# Is there an XSLT floating around anywhere that converts Apple Pages documents to decent HTML?

Tags: html, xslt, iwork

Apple’s word processor/DTP app Pages saves its files as zipped folders, containing an XML file with the content inside, and attachments (e.g. images) saved as files.

I’m looking to convert this content into decent HTML: `<p>`s for things that look like paragraphs, tables translated into HTML tables, images and links maintained.

I don’t need to copy over styles from the Pages document.

Is there an XSLT floating around the internet anywhere that does this? [A chap called Davin Granroth wrote one](http://blog.davingranroth.com/2009/11/xslt-to-get-text-from-apple-pages-documents/) that’s a good starting point for getting the text out, but it doesn’t handle images, tables or links.

I quite fancy having a go myself, but it seems like someone would have written this already.

Comment: Having Pages save it as HTML is not an option, I suppose?

Comment: Actually, Pages does export to ePub, and the HTML produced in this export doesn’t look bad at all — `<p>`s, `<img>`s and `<table>`s seem to be present and correct. Pop that in as an answer, and you’re golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not for some kind of automated, server-side processing, you may want to try the export functions of Pages itself.